# Python 2.7. Reading class instance property leads to error of type AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, boost

I have run into an issue when trying to wrap the boost library with python code. I have the following classes associated with a Python wrapper around the boost library.

class Edge2:
    x1 = -1
    y1 = -1
    x2 = -1
    y2 = -1 
    is_primary = False
    site = -1
    is_linear = False

```
def __init__(self, x1,y1,x2,y2, is_primary, site, is_linear):
    self.x1 = x1
    self.y1 = y1
    self.x2 = x2
    self.y2 = y2
    self.is_primary = is_primary
    self.site = site
    self.is_linear = is_linear
```

class VoronoiCell:
    cellId = -1
    segments = None

```
def __init__(self,cellId):
    self.cellId = cellId
    self.segments = []
```

As I am iterating through my C++ results, and convert the information I need into a python object of type Voronoi cell. And the list of segments is a collection of elements of type Edge2.

```
            if(c_edges2[i-1].site == edge2.site):
                print "Append segment to cell"
                self.outputCells[-1].segments.append(edge2)
            else:
                print "Append segment to cell"
                cell = VoronoiCell(edge2.site)
                cell.segments.append(Edge2(x1,y1,x2,y2,edge2.isPrimary, edge2.site, edge2.isLinear))
                self.outputCells.append(cell)
```

Yet, when I try to iterate through the results through an external python, my segments are marked as dictionaries, when I expect classes. And they are not even proper dictionaries since I can't even use the dictionary syntax to access the class members.

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'x1'

```
cells = pv.GetCellSegments()
print "Cell Count: " + str(len(cells))
for c in cells:
    print "Cell identifier: {0}".format(c.cellId)#Works fine
    for s in c.segments:
         print "     " + str(s.x1)#Fails with error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'x1'
```

I am a bit puzzled. Does anyone know why I get this error message?

Comment: Apparently, `c.segments` doesn't contain exclusively `Edge2` instances, but also at least one plain Python `dict` instance.  Just print `s` in the inner loop to see what's going on.  We can't help you, since the error isn't in the code parts you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sven!

Not the exact answer but you led me on the right track... and you were close! I forgot how simple problems sometime are when you let them be for a while.

When I do self.outputCells[-1].segments.append(edge2) I am actually appending the mapped C struct, not the python class. I should have been calling my constructor like I do after wards

```
cell.segments.append(Edge2(x1,y1,x2,y2,edge2.isPrimary, edge2.site, edge2.isLinear))
```

Thanks again Sven for his comment!

Fabien